# Search by file name in the Media Library

Tags: wordpress

Inside the Admin Panel, in Media -> Library, how to search media files by **file name** in "search media" box?

I know the file name is placed in the "GUID" column in the database, but I don't know where I can find the piece of code responsible for media search, ex. MySQL `select`.

Now it only searches in the `post_title` column. I also tried to find `$_REQUEST['s']`, but with without result.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found a solution in [WordPress Developers #45153](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45153/12615), but here are all related Q&A's:

- [How to filter post listing using a custom field?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/16637/12615)
- [Limiting Admin Backend Search to Title](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/45153/12615)
- [Better search for Wordpress admin backend](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/10685/12615)

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'guid_search_so_14940004', 10, 2 );

function guid_search_so_14940004( $search, $a_wp_query ) 
{
    global $wpdb, $pagenow;

    // Only Admin side && Only Media Library page
    if ( !is_admin() && 'upload.php' != $pagenow ) 
        return $search;

    // Original search string:
    // AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%search-string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%search-string%')))
    $search = str_replace(
        'AND ((', 
        'AND (((' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts.guid LIKE \'%' . $_GET['s'] . '%\') OR ', 
        $search
    ); 

    return $search;
}
```

There was a suggestion that I need to verify, but seems good:

> Change `$_GET['s']` to `$a_wp_query->query_vars['s']` so that this also works when the search function is called via an ajax POST, eg when using the "Create Gallery" dialogue.

Comment: Works great.
Just put it in `functions.php` in your theme catalog.
Thank You!

Comment: @Arek-Krakiewicz.pl, it's better to [create your own plugin](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/72160/12615) ;)

Comment: Neat solution so far. But be aware that the media search is extended by looking for the `guid` value which by deafult is the URL of post entries (respectively of the files). So, if let's say your domain is _example.com_ and your uploaded media file's name is _example-image.jpg_ you would get **all files** as result **when searching for "example"**.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update to this answer. The code above only works for the Media Library options page and doesn't apply to any ajax requests which occur when inserting an image into the content area.

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'guid_search_so_14940004', 10, 2 );

function guid_search_so_14940004( $search, $a_wp_query ) {
    global $wpdb, $pagenow;

    // Only Admin side && Only Media Library page
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        return $search;
    }

    if ( 'admin-ajax.php' !== $pagenow && 'upload.php' !== $pagenow ) {
        return $search;
    }

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['action'] ) && 'query-attachments' === $_REQUEST['action'] && ! empty( $_REQUEST['query']['s'] ) ) {
        $search_string = $_REQUEST['query']['s'];
    }

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['s'] ) || empty( $_REQUEST['s'] ) ) {
        $search_string = $_REQUEST['s'];
    }

    if ( ! isset( $search_string ) || empty( $search_string ) ) {
        return $search;
    }

    // Original search string:
    // AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%search-string%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%search-string%')))
    $search = str_replace(
        'AND ((',
        'AND (((' . $wpdb->posts . '.guid LIKE \'%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $search_string ) . '%\') OR ',
        $search
    );

    return $search;
}
```