# Wordpress - Media's search bar doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.6

I have a WordPress (WordPress 4.6) With the theme : TrueMag.

My media's search bar does not work, it always show nothing no matter what you write...

Anybody have any idea please ?

Thank you very much

Comment: Does this help you with your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14940004/search-by-file-name-in-the-media-library Also have you made any recent changes recently. Was it always like this or did it just start to happen. Please make sure to update your question if you have made any changes lately.

Comment: Contact their support if this was always like this